# Is calling DispatchMessage in win32 programs necessary?

Tags: windows, winapi

Win32 programs generally have a message loop that loops calling **GetMessage** or **PeekMessage**, and then calls **DispatchMessage** to dispatch the message to the window proceedure of the relevant window.

But is there any need to actually do this? Can I instead just look in the **MSG** object directly in the message loop and perform the actions needed there without calling **DispatchMessage**? I'm talking about cases where I have one single window with no other window controls, for example if the window is only used as a direct3d display window, so messages will always be directed at the only window.

Mostly I'm just curious but also it might lead to certain aspects of my code being cleaner too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You call `DispatchMessage` to have the message delivered to proper window, to its "window proc". You think you have one window only, but is it really the only one? `COM` will create helper windows, other subsystems might create helper hidden windows as well, who is going to deliver messages posted to shared message queue and addressed to those windows. Without having to think a lot about these details you have API to dispatch them. And you have to do it because those subsystems are relying on presence of message pump.

`Spy++` Windows SDK tool might help you with seeing how many windows you really have.

Still if you indeed have the only window, it does not make much of a difference whether you handler is called from DispatchMessage internals, or directly by your message pump.

Comment: `DispatchMessage` and `CallWindowProc` also do things like considering windows hooks. Even with a single window you need to use them. I believe some messages cannot be processed correctly outside of `DispatchMessage` but I don't have any examples off the top of my head. Maybe things like `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: @tenfour, perhaps more correctly is to say that some messages will be anyway called via WindowProc, and won't exist as separate message on the queue. So, WindowProc is a must in any case. Still those posted on the queue can be handled both ways. I cannot think of reasons why one would want to handle them right there on the pump side.

Comment: Note also that you may think that you have a single window, but many components (such as DirectX) will create windows on your behalf, so you actually have multiple windows. You just don't realize it.